# Page for Page Redirect in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect, dns, webapp2

I have recently changed domain name for a webapp I run on Google App Engine and I am wondering if there is a simple way to do a page for page redirect from my old website to the new domain. Everything code wise is staying exactly the same but I just want it to go to the new domain.

I am using python and the webapp2 framework for the web application.

I know I could go through and for every single handler do:

```
webapp2.redirect('the specific url', permanent=True)
```

But I am hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: do you have a `BaseHandler` or do all your handlers subclass from `webapp2.RequestHandler`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do a global url rewrite.  Basically, your webapp is already matching the requested URL and directing it to the appropriate code in the `webapp2.WSGIApplication` object, so you can simply have all URLs match to the same `class`, probably with `('/*', myclass)` or something like that, and then have that page redirect users to the corresponding page of your new site.  Example:

```py
import webapp2
newdomain = 'http://www.mynewdomain.com/'

class RedirectPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, restofurl):
        return webapp2.redirect(newdomain + restofurl, permanent=True)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([webapp2.Route(r'/<restofurl:.*>', handler=RedirectPage, name='redirect_page')])
```

Unfortunately, I can't currently test this to be 100% sure that it works, but I know it would work at least in theory.  Ideally, I'd prefer an Apache URL rewrite, but I don't think you have that option.